# How to create short links in Next.js?

Tags: next.js, url-rewriting, short-url

I have a blog made with Next.js and data is coming from CMS (Headless WordPress).
Assume every post has a title and an id. I want to create short links for my blog, so every `site.com/blog/[id]` (or `site.com/blog/?id=[id]`) automatically redirects to `site.com/blog/[title]`.
Also, it should be dynamic; so every time a new post is created, the short link should be generated too.

I'm a little bit confused about how to do this. Should I do it per post? Should I define redirect/rewrites in Next.js config? Should I do it server-side, like with `.htaccess`? Should it be redirect or rewrite?

Also in GitHub Discussions:
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/discussions/39897

Comment: How is the mapping from `id` to `title` done/handled? Are you using SSG or SSR for your dynamic page?

Comment: That's another part of the confusion :) I'm using SSG. Since I'm getting data with GraphQL, I can get title from id with a simple custom function like `getTitleById{id}`, but I'm not sure if it's possible to use it to generate shortlinks. Also, I have access to both `id` and `title` when generating posts, and using a function might be unnecessary.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Next.js [middleware](https://nextjs.org/docs/advanced-features/middleware) to dynamically redirect the short URLs to their long URLs counterparts.

Unlike `redirects` in `next.config.js` that are generated at build time, middleware runs on each request allowing for newly created pages to be redirected to.

Add the following `middleware.js` file at the same level as the `pages` folder.

```js
// middleware.js
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import getTitleById from '<path-to-getTitleById>'; // Replace with your own function

export function middleware(req) {
    // Check if path matches short URL (`/b?id=1` or `b/1`)
    if (req.nextUrl.pathname === '/b' || req.nextUrl.pathname.startsWith('/b/')) {
        // Get `id` from URL path or query parameter
        const [,,idFromPath] = req.nextUrl.pathname.split('/');
        const id = idFromPath ?? req.nextUrl.searchParams.get('id');
        const title = getTitleById(id);

        // If a `title` for given `id` exists, redirect to `/blog/[title]` page
        if (title) {
            return NextResponse.redirect(new URL(`/blog/${title}`, req.url));
        }
    }

    return NextResponse.next();
}
```

The above will redirect URLs like `/b?id=1` or `/b/1` to the appropriate `/blog/slug-for-id-1`, given that `getTitleById` is able to do that mapping.